# Copy folder in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'am trying to copy a folder from a textbox a user specify to another location a user specify but this code only copies the file to the destination and not the folder. I'am using Visual Studio 2005.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim strDate As String
    strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    Dim sFolderpath
    Dim dFolderpath
    Dim fs

    fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sFolderpath = TextBox1.Text
    dFolderpath = TextBox6.Text + "\"
    fs.createfolder(dFolderpath & strDate)
    fs.copyfolder(sFolderpath, dFolderpath & strDate)
```

- First the script create a folder in a destination specified by the user in textbox1
  and name it after todays date
- Then I would like to copy a folder from a destination specified by the user in textbox6

It only copies the files to the destination not the folder itself. 
Value in textbox1 = C:\Test\Test2.
Value in textbox6 = K:\Backup

Please help!

Comment: You're not using VB6 and Visual Studio 2005, because VB6 was never part of Visual Studio. Do you mean `vb.net` instead?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2005 and have created a new project> Microsoft Application under Visual Basic. I'll be glad if I could have some help to copy the folder (with its content) to the new location specified by the user in textbox6.

Comment: We need to know first which language you're actually using, as the proper solution is different for each of the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

It's a weird mix of VB.Net and VBScript...

I ~think~ this is what you're after though:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fs As Object = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim sFolderpath As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim sourceFolderName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sFolderpath)

    Dim strDate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim dFolderpath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(TextBox6.Text, strDate)
    fs.createfolder(dFolderpath)
    dFolderpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dFolderpath, sourceFolderName)
    fs.createfolder(dFolderpath)

    fs.copyfolder(sFolderpath, dFolderpath)
End Sub
```

You may also be interested in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Well, I am a newbee at programming and try to find answer in the web. Thank you so much. How can I add more textboxes to this code so the user can copy other folders too? I have now 5 textboxes so the user can choose from 5 location.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to follow the pattern but I could not find a solution to add more textboxes to this code. I would be glad if you could provide a solution or give me a hint what to do. I have 5 textboxes so the user can "browse" for 5 locations to copy to a destination folder user specify in textbox6.text. When user clicks "Button1" I would like the code to copy all the folders specified in the texboxes to the location specified.